Can my PC support, and how do I install, ROCm 6.1?
I am trying to learn and run some machine learning code (PyTorch) on my computer for astrophysical image data improvement.
I would like to install PyTorch 2.4, and it has the option to install it with a Compute Platform of ROCm 6.2. I believe I have a ROCm that is close to, but not quite 6.2. Can and how do I upgrade to ROCm 6.2 on my ubuntu?
For reference, my device has the following specifications:

    Hardware Model: Lenovo ThinkPad X13 Gen 4
    …
    Processor: AMD Ryzen™ 7 PRO 7840U w/ Radeon™ 780M Graphics × 16
    Graphics: AMD Radeon™ Graphics
    Firmware Version: R29ET56W (1.30 )
    …
    OS Name: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    OS Build: (null)
    OS Type: 64-bit
    GNOME Version: 46
    Windowing System: Wayland
    Kernel Version: Linux 6.8.0-47-generic


I seem to have an older version(s) of ROCm. When I use “apt show rocm…” in the command line, I get:
1.)
Package: rocminfo
Version: 5.7.1-3build1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/devel
Origin: Ubuntu
Installed-Size: 95.2 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.3.1), libhsa-runtime64-1 (>= 5.7.1~), libstdc++6 (>= 11), python3, pciutils, kmod
Download-Size: 25.6 kB

2.)
Package: rocm-cmake
Version: 6.0.0-1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/devel
Origin: Ubuntu
Installed-Size: 138 kB
Download-Size: 25.6 kB

3.)
Package: rocm-device-libs-17
Version: 6.0+git20231212.5a852ed-2
Priority: optional
Section: universe/libs
Source: rocm-device-libs
Origin: Ubuntu
Installed-Size: 3,324 kB
Download-Size: 549 kB

4.)
Package: rocm-smi
Version: 5.7.0-1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/utils
Source: rocm-smi-lib
Origin: Ubuntu
Installed-Size: 227 kB
Depends: python3:any, librocm-smi64-1 (= 5.7.0-1)
Download-Size: 52.9 kB

None of the version numbers are at 6.2 or higher, so I think I should upgrade before installing, yes? I've seen some information here, but haven't understood it enough to successfully install it. Anyone familiar with upgrading ROCm that can help me here?   :-)
